# Non-numeric argument when attempting to normalize a column using R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I'm trying to normalize the values in a dataframe column. (Dataframe is called "GDP".) Here's my data:

```
Value.2015
200
100
150
700
890
```

I continue to receive the "non-numeric argument to binary operator" error when attempting to run the below code to get the column normalized.

```
((GDP$value.2015) - (min(GDP$value.2015)))/((max(GDP$value.2015)) - (min(GDP$value.2015)))
```

Any suggestions for how to properly proceed without receiving the error? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Firstly, check your capitalization. Then check your types via `str(GDP)`.

Comment: Try `GDP$value.2015 <- as.numeric(as.character(GDP$value.2015))` before normalization.

Comment: @user3640617 That worked! Thank you. What did that do that I wasn't doing previously? (I'm quite new to R.)

Comment: Either when you loaded the dataset (I assume from a .csv file) or when you performed some operation on them, R turned the columns into factors. `as.numeric(as.character(x))` turns them back into numeric data that you can perform simple arithmetic with. You'll encounter that a lot, when you use econ data.

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis Thank you, that's very helpful. Is there a quick way to perform that same operation for 56 columns of data without having to write out the column names in the code? (I.e., could I replace x above with [,1:56] to achieve the same result?

Comment: @R.Baratheon I'd try something like this `df[,1:56]<- apply(df[,1:56], 2, function(x) as.character(as.numeric(x)))`